# Writing a Linear Expression for a MIP in or-tools

Tags: java, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to write a linear expression in or-tools using Java and then add it in a constraint.

As already seen in the documentation [linear_expr](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/linear_solver/linear_expr/) and in [GitHub](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/v7.0/ortools/linear_solver/linear_expr.h#L103) there is a way to do such.

Nevertheless, it is for me unclear how to use this for an example like this:

```
linear_expr: offset + sum_{i in S} a_i*x_i
constraint: linear_expr <= y_j
```

**x** and **y** are decision variables

This is how I think it should look like.

```
    /*define variables and parameters*/
double offset = Math.random();
int S = 10;
ArrayList<Double> aList = new ArrayList<Double>();
/*define variable x and parameter a*/
HashMap<Integer,LinearExpr> x = new HashMap<Integer,LinearExpr>();
for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
LinearExpr x_variable = solver.makeBoolVar("x_variable_" + i);
    x.put(i,x_variable);
    aList.set(i,Math.random());
}
int K = 20;
/*define variable y*/
HashMap<Integer,LinearExpr> y = new HashMap<Integer,LinearExpr>();
for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
    LinearExpr y_variable = solver.makeNumVar(0,MPSolver.infinity(),"y_variable_" + j);
    y.put(j,y_variable);
}
/*linear_expr: offset + sum_{i in S} a_i*x_i
constraint: linear_expr <= y_j
*/
LinearExpr linear_expr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
linear_expr = linear_expr + x.get(i) * aList.get(i)
}
linear_expr = linear_expr + offset;
/*define constraint*/
for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
    MPConstraint constraint = solver.makeConstraint(linear_expr,MPSolver.infinity(),"constraint_"+j);
    constraint.setCoefficient(y.get(j),1);
}
```

Furthermore, it is impossible to create a LinearExpr variable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no such API in java, and you cannot implement it as you wrote because you cannot overload the + and * operators.

You need to use setCoefficient on the constraint object.

Now you can create a class with 3 fields (list of variables, list of coefficients, constant) and the appropriate addTerm(), addVar() and setConstant() method.

This being said, the API you use suggest you are only using Boolean variables and integer coefficients.

You can have a look at the CP-SAT API that offers a [LinearExpr class](http://google.github.io/or-tools/java/interfacecom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat_1_1LinearExpr.html).
See this [gentle introduction](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md) and the [Java API](http://google.github.io/or-tools/java/namespacecom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat.html)

Comment: I do use the setCoefficient method: `constraint.setCoefficient(y.get(j),1);`. If I got it right, in order to write the following expression `offset + sum_{i in S} a_i*x_i` I need to write my own class? Is there no other way to write it without the use of the LinearExpr class? Is it still possible for the variable x to be of type MPVariable? Would this be possible in Python?

Comment: The LinearExpr is C++ only. You could rewrite it in Java and add a solver.add() method to parse. I plan to implement this in the next major release, but I have no timeline yet.